# How can I run my integration tests on DevOps for multiple services?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, integration

I want my services to trigger the same tests when one of them is released.It's that possible?Thank you !

Comment: Are the integration tests in release pipeline? are the services built in build pipeline? when a service is built in build pipeline and its build artifacts is published, the integration tests should run?

Comment: Yes,the tests are in the release pipeline,services same build in piepline,when one of the service is released the tests are running in different enviroments

Comment: Are your service is released via azure pipeline too? I was thinking if you can add a script task to call the rest api to trigger the integration test release pipeline in the pipepline which releases your servcie.

Comment: Yes,so all the services are via azure piepline too,I don't want for each service to create new artifacts,I want to use what tests I have in different services,when one of the services are released the test will trigger there,when the second is released, the tests will trigger on the second service.

Comment: Another question i am not sure. Is it that when one service is released to an environment, then the tests should run on this environment.  how is the environment which the integration tests run against configured in the release pipeline. Or is it that the integration test pipeline donot need to change any thing, it just need to be triggered and run the test when one service is released?

Comment: Yes exactly as you say,it just need to be triggered and run the test when one service is released

Answer (score 0):

You can call [create release rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) in the service pipeline to trigger a release to run the integration test. See below steps:

1, Add a script task at the end of the each service pipeline to call create release rest api. For below example, to run below scripts in the [powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops).

```
$rurl="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0-preview.8"

# the definitionId is the definitionId of release pipeline of the integration tests
$body='{
 
 "definitionId": 3

}'
 
$result1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $rurl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method post  -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

You can get the definitionId of your tests release pipeline from the address bar.
Go the release page --> click the release pipeline which run the test--> You will see the definitionId on the address bar.

[image]

If the service pipelines are in the different projects from test release pipeline. You need to go the test release pipeline security setting page to allow service pipelines **create release** permission.(Search for the `{Service ProjectName} Build Service ({OrganizationName})`)

[image]

So that, when the service pipeline is finished releasing the service and the powershell task at the end will be executed. The script in the powershell task will call create release rest api. Then test release pipeline will be triggered and run the integration tests.

Comment: I created my powershell script with the code above but I am getting errors.

Comment: 2020-07-21T09:45:16.5297523Z Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to 
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5297903Z delimit the name.
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5298734Z At D:\a\_temp\52f9338c-3c70-4c3e-9d32-662e8cc3fd79.ps1:12 char:159
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5299237Z + ... CESSTOKEN"} -Method post  -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5299739Z +                                                                         ~
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5300134Z The string is missing the terminator: ".

Comment: 2020-07-21T09:45:16.5300985Z At D:\a\_temp\52f9338c-3c70-4c3e-9d32-662e8cc3fd79.ps1:12 char:77
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5301435Z + ...  = "Bearer" $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method post  -Body $body -Cont ...
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5301854Z +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5302307Z Unexpected token '$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method post  -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5302737Z if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath variable:\LASTEXITCODE)) {
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5303615Z } else {

Comment: 2020-07-21T09:45:16.5304267Z     exit $LASTEXITCODE
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5304879Z }' in expression or statement.
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5305621Z At D:\a\_temp\52f9338c-3c70-4c3e-9d32-662e8cc3fd79.ps1:12 char:76
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5306417Z + ... oke-RestMethod -Uri $rurl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer" $env:SY ...
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5307386Z +                                                                  ~
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5307675Z The hash literal was incomplete.

Comment: 2020-07-21T09:45:16.5307967Z     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5308341Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive
2020-07-21T09:45:16.5308621Z  
2020-07-21T09:45:16.6943406Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-07-21T09:45:16.7391772Z ##[section]Finishing: Integration Tests

Comment: It seems the error comes from your scripts. You need to troubleshoot your scripts and fix the error.